# run multiple values from a file on a single command one after another

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, files

run multiple values from a file on a single command one after another

I have a the following command

```
    ./test.sh -f test.txt

     Completed Success
```

I have 1000 of inputs to be passed to the same script which I have in a file example.txt.

every time the script executes and output successful.

```
cat example.txt

test.txt
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

etc

I want the command to fetch each and every line and execute in a batch process like

```
./test.sh -f test.txt
  Completed Success
./test.sh -f test1.txt
  Completed Success
./test.sh -f test2.txt
  Completed Success
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` or `while` loop:

```
for i in `cat example.txt`; do ./test.sh -f $i;done
```

Or

```
while read i; do ./test.sh -f $i;done < example.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
< example.txt xargs -n 1 -t ./test.sh -f
```

Comment: it breaks after the first execution

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: instead of `<` use `cat` and pipe . `cat example.txt | xargs -n 1 -t ./test.sh -f` will run through all lines